# Orphaned organization in Trello how to gain ownership

Tags: trello, trello-organization

When first signing up to Trello I created an organization, however that organization does not appear in my profile or on the Boards page of my account.

If I go to the organization's  profile page, I am the sole owner among several members. However even when trying to add a board from the profile page, the organization doesn't show up in the create board dialogue, only other organizations I am a member of.

How do I gain control of this rogue organization?

Comment: How odd. It sounds like you should contact Trello support: https://trello.com/help

Comment: Thanks, Clare. I wrote to support yesterday afternoon and they were able to fix the issue very quickly. No idea if it's a repeatable bug, they agreed it was very unusual.

Comment: Hi Sean! Glad we were able to get this resolved for you. Hmmm, so since this is a freak occurrence, should we maybe close the question? It's unlikely to be useful to others.